# How can I send the results in a list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Outputs are on the text but I want to outputs in a list or listview for choosing of them.  How can I do this?Note:This code was written in a THREAD

```
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

                     try {
                         Vector ls=sftpChannel.ls("/home/volkan/Masaüstü");

                         for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++){
                             text +=sftpChannel.pwd()+"/";
                             text += (((LsEntry)ls.get(i)).getFilename())+"\n";

                         }
                         t.post(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                t.setText(text);
                             }
                         });
                     } catch (SftpException e1) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     }
```